# Finding two regular hexagons such that lines are parallel

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am looking to describe the following construction of two nested regular hexagons where the red lines in the picture would be parallel. How would I go about describing the nesting of these hexagons so that the lines are parallel? How would the points of the inner regular hexagon have to be placed so that we would get these parallel lines?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, place the hexagons on a coordinate plane such that the vertices of the outer hexagon are $$(2,0), (1,\sqrt{3}), (-1,\sqrt{3}), (-2,0), (-1,-\sqrt{3}), (1,-\sqrt{3}),$$ and the inner hexagon's vertices are the same as the outer vertices scaled by a factor of $r < 1$.  Then, for instance, we require the slope of the line joining $(-1,\sqrt{3})$ to $(r, r \sqrt{3})$ to be equal to the slope of the line joining $(-r, r \sqrt{3})$ to $(2,0)$.  That is to say, $$\frac{r \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{3}}{r - (-1)} = \frac{r \sqrt{3} - 0}{-r - 2}.$$  Solving this equation yields $$r = \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2} \approx 0.618,$$ hence the smaller hexagon has vertices $$\left(\sqrt{5} - 1, 0\right), \left(\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{5} - 1)}{2} \right), \ldots.$$
In other words, the ratio of the side length of the smaller hexagon to the side length of the larger is $r$.